# Jquery ajax request to server returning error code 405 on live server?

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, ajax

The following code is working fine when I run the application on localhost but it is not working when hosted on the live server, as the ajax request returned a error code

> 405 HTTP method get is not supported by this url.

I have making a get request and also handling this request in doGet method then what went wrong when I try to run this code on live server.

NOTE: **only posting the required code js code**

`Client side code`

```
 $.ajax({

           type:"GET",
           url:"fetchdata1",
           data:"cat="+cat,
           success:function(data){  

           }           
        });
```

`server side code`

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

      String cat = request.getParameter("cat");
      PrintWriter out= response.getWriter();
      ArrayList<product> p = new ArrayList();

    try {
            con=ConnectionManager.getConnection();
            ps = con.prepareStatement("Select product_id,images.product_name,image_name,company_name,price "
                + "from images,products where images.product_name = products.product_name AND "
                + "category_name = ?");

            ps.setString(1,cat);
            rs=ps.executeQuery(); 
            while(rs.next())
            {
                 product pr =new product();
                 pr.id = rs.getInt("product_id");
                 pr.name = rs.getString("product_name");
                 pr.company =rs.getString("company_name");
                 pr.image = rs.getString("image_name");
                 pr.price = rs.getDouble("price");
                 p.add(pr);        
            }

            String json = new Gson().toJson(p);
            response.setContentType("application/json");
            out.println(json);

        }
```

Comment: What happens when an exception occurs? I don't see the `catch` block.